# Side scrolling menu with gesture removable items

Tags: user-interface, windows-phone-8, menu

I am trying to create a menu (currently a ListBox containing Images) for an app (WP8 specifically, but general principal will be the same for other environments) with the behavior determined by the initial part of each gesture:

- dragging/swiping the menu left or right will cause the menu to scroll left or right
- dragging an item up from the menu (which is at bottom of screen) will allow it to be detached (or recreated) and placed in another container.

Roughly speaking, I understand how to drag-and-drop the element, and to make a side-scrolling menu, but I am having difficulties in putting the two together and determining whether to be in "menu scroll" mode, or "drag and drop" mode, and how to switch between the two programmatically.

```
<ListBox Height="100"
    ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
    Grid.Row="1"
    Name="MainMenuPicker">
  <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      </StackPanel>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Image Source="{Binding Path=Source}" Tap="Image_Tap"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Currently, horizontal scrolling is taken care of by `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"`

I attempted to  have a ManipluationStarted, ManipulationDelta etc to determine direction of gesture, but didn't get very far. I currently have a `Tap` event handler on the Image that moves moving to another parent container.

Questions:
1. How can I determine if a gesture is a side-to-side movement on the menu (ListBox) as a whole, or a drag (upwards) of an Image within the ListBox?

1. How can I programmatically set each case so that the functionality behaves as described?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need to use Flick events,and use HorizaltalVelocity and vertcalvelocity to detect and distinguish between left-right and top-down swipes.

[check this sample for better understanding](https://github.com/PedroLamas/WPtoolkit/blob/master/PhoneToolkitSample8/Samples/GestureSample.xaml.cs)